# How to set/change another post author by custom fields or something else?

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, author

I need help! (sorry for my poor English, I'm from Russia)
How I can to set/change another post author by custom fields or something else?
For example:
I want to public post, but define another post author by author login.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change author? If yes, you can easily do from admin area. Go to `domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php`, press `Quick Edit` and select the user from dropdown.

Comment: I know about it, but on my website many authors and select ones in small list very difficlt and uncomfortable for me.

Comment: Then use [wordpress Bluk Edit Feature](http://wordpress.tv/2009/01/14/using-quick-edit-and-bulk-edit-to-manage-your-posts-in-half-the-time/)